# Storing data in a var that also contains an element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get an object like:

```
p.box = $('.box');
```

And then also store info in the same var like it's width, height, name, in an array:

```
p.box{
  height: 10,
  width: 10,
  name: bunny
}
```

I don;t really want to store it as .data on the html element. Is there another way?

Comment: you can freely set properties on a javascript object, such as `p.box.height = 10; p.box.width = 10; p.box.name = bunny`

Comment: or `p.box.options = {height: 10,  width: 10,  name: bunny}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $.extend( object1, object2 ), you can find the docs here ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ ).

Example,

```
var x = $.extend( $('.box'), { height: 10, width: 10, name: "bunny" });
```

So, you can access data like

console.log(x.height);

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since `$('.box')` returns a jQuery object, it should be stored in a different property (of the  var).
Here is an example :

```
p.box.obj = $('.box');
p.box.props = {
  height: 10,
  width: 10,
  name: bunny
}
```

`p.box.props` will hold object containing info. To get value of `name`, use `p.box.props.name`.

Is there any particular reason why you don't want to store info in html elements ?